# Mayer-Vietoris in reduced homology for a torus.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

By using the Mayer-Vietoris sequence in reduced homology :

I have to calculate the homology groups of :

The torus $\mathbb{T}^2 :=[0;1]^2 /\mathcal{T}$ by using the following decomposition
 $X_1 := \mathbb{T}^{2} -\{(1/2;1/2)\}$, $X_2 = ]0,1[^{2}$ et $A=X_1 \cap X_2$.

$\mathcal{T}$ is an equivalence relation meaning that we have identified the boudaries of the square $[0;1]^2$ : $(1,t)\sim (0,t)$ and $(t,1)\sim (t,0)$;$t\in[0;1]$. The point $(1/2;1/2)$ is the center of the square.

I have already done this work : the rose with 2 petals is a retract by deformation of $X_1$ so 
$\tilde{H}_0(X_1)=\mathbb{Z}$
$\tilde{H}_1(X_1)=\mathbb{Z\oplus\mathbb Z}$ and $\tilde{H}_n(X_1)=0$ for $n\geq 2$

$\tilde{H}_n(X_2)=0$ for all $n$.

But i am stuck here. How can i compute $H_1(\mathbb T^2)$ and $H_2(\mathbb T^2)$ ?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you computed $\tilde H_*(A)$? And have you written out the Mayer-Vietoris sequence and substituted the values that you know for the various terms?

Comment: @LeeMosher But how can i geometrically describe $A$ ? It is a square without boundary and a hole in the middle but how can i compute its homology ?

Comment: You compute the homology of $A$ the way you computed the homology of $X_1$, by figuring out what $A$ deformation retracts to.

Comment: @LeeMosher That is my problem...i do not know how to retract $A$.

Comment: What is $\mathcal T$? What does $(1/2; 1/2)$ mean? One can guess, but it would be much better if you clarified this non-standard notation.

Comment: @AymanHourieh You are right. $\mathcal{T}$ is an equivalence relation meaning that we have identified the boudaries of a square : $(1,t)\sim (0,t)$ and $(t,1)\sim (t,0)$;$t\in[0;1]$. The point $(1/2;1/2)$ is the center of my square.

Comment: Dear @Far, please edit your question with this information.

Comment: @LeeMosher I think the deformation retract of $A$ is the circle $S^1$...

Comment: That sounds right.

Comment: @LeeMosher I have the following reduced sequence : $0\rightarrow H_2(\mathbb{T}^2) \rightarrow H_1(\mathbb{S}^1)\rightarrow H_1(X_1)\times H_1(X_2) \rightarrow .. .$. How can i show that $H_2(\mathbb{T}^2)=\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: Have you computed the homomorphisms in the sequence?

Comment: @LeeMosher I am working on it but i am stuck here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've worked out so far, the key to this problem is computation of the homomorphism
$$\mathbb{Z} \approx H_1(\mathbb{S}^1) \xrightarrow{j_*} H_1(A) \xrightarrow{i_*} H_1(X_1) \approx \mathbb{Z}^2
$$
In this sequence, $i_*$ is the homomorphism induced by the inclusion $i : A \hookrightarrow X_1$, and $j_*$ is the isomorphism induced by a homotopy equivalence $j :\mathbb{S}^1 \to A$. Once you've computed that homomorphism, it will follow that $H_2(\mathbb{T}^2)$ is isomorphic to its kernel.

Let me give some further hints, without giving the whole thing away.

Your work will be aided by deriving a simple expression for a function $f : \mathbb{S}^1 \to X_1$ which is homotopic to the composition $\mathbb{S}^1 \xrightarrow{i} A \xrightarrow{j} X_1$.

If you understand how the boundary of a square is glued to a rose $X_1$ to form $\mathbb{T}^2$, then you should be able to use the description of that gluing to guess and to prove a formula for $f$.

And once you have a formula for $f : S^1 \to X_1$, you should be able to "abelianize" that formula to obtain a formula for the induced function $f_* = j_* \circ i_* : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: Thank you. The idea is clear but i am not able to write down a formula for $f$. I can glue the boundary of the square (the square is homeomorphic to a 2-cell) to the wedge of the circles ?

Comment: @Far: Yes, you can glue in that manner. Furthermore, the actual formula for that gluing **is** the formula for $f : \mathbb{S}^1 \to X_1$, up to homotopy.